# How to add image to table view cell based on user selection

Tags: xcode, swift

Basically I have a table view controller that I am populating with transactions. The user can choose to enter either a payment or credit via a segmented control when they tap the add button.

I was trying to figure out how I can display an image of (for example) a green arrow for a credit, and a red arrow for a payment in each cell based on what the user selected? I am using Swift by the way.

This is how the cell currently looks. I would like the arrow to be just to the left of the 'Amount' label.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that I currently have...

ThirdViewController:

```
var arrayObject = ArrayData()

class ThirdViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBAction func addNewPaymentButton(sender : AnyObject) {
    //Add code for adding a new payment here
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// #pragma mark - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return arrayObject.paymentsArray().count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:CustomTransactionTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell
    cell.paymentNameLabel.text = (arrayObject.paymentsArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String
    cell.costLabel.text = (arrayObject.costArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String
    cell.dateLabel.text = (arrayObject.dateArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as String

    if transactionType == 0 {
        cell.paymentArrowImage.hidden = false
    } else if transactionType == 1 {
        cell.creditArrowImage.hidden = false
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        //Add code for deletion
    }
}
}
```

This is the only relevant code for the FifthViewController:

```
        arrayDataPayments.addObject(transactionName)
    arrayDataCost.addObject("£\(finalUserBudget)")
    arrayDataDate.addObject(transactionDateInputted)
```

ArrayData

```
var arrayDataPayments: NSMutableArray = []
var arrayDataCost: NSMutableArray = []
var arrayDataDate: NSMutableArray = []

class ArrayData: NSObject {

func paymentsArray() -> NSMutableArray { return arrayDataPayments }

func costArray() -> NSMutableArray { return arrayDataCost }

func dateArray() -> NSMutableArray { return arrayDataDate }
}
```

CustomTransactionTableViewCell

```
class CustomTransactionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var paymentNameLabel : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var costLabel : UILabel
    @IBOutlet var creditArrowImage: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet var paymentArrowImage: UIImageView

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Please excuse the global variables. They are only temporary.

Comment: I've added my current code as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to work exactly like everything else about a table view. There's going to be an image view in your cell. Whether an image is showing in that image view, and what image is showing, is going to have to be part of your *model*, so that the model takes care of *knowing* this information with respect to each row. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you *manifest* that info from the model in the view, setting the image view's image in the cell for whatever row you are asked about.

Comment: I'm new to Xcode so I might be doing this completely wrong, but I added two images into the cell for the payment and the credit and I put IBOutlets in the CustomTransactionTableViewCell class. I then put an if statement in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: in the ThirdViewController to hide the correct image based on the users choice. At the moment I am getting an unresolved identifier image. Am I doing this correctly, and if so how do I access the IBOutlets from a different class?

Comment: Thanks for the link, however I solved the issue by simply adding the identifier before the image.hidden.

Comment: Actually, I'm having issues with the image being overwritten. When you enter a credit and then switch to a payment, all of the images in the cells are switched to the payment arrow. I've put my updated code in the original post.

Comment: You are making THE most elementary, common mistake - forgetting that the cells will be reused later. You must set the complete state for every possible case - hidden or not hidden, _explicitly_, for both image views for every cell you are asked about. Please take the time to read the discussion I pointed you to! It discusses this exact issue using almost this very same example (at the end of the section entitle "The Three Big Questions" - http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#SECtableViewSections).

Comment: I managed to get it working properly now. I put the transaction type number into another array and used it in an if statement to display the corresponding image for each input. I'll definitely have a read through the link you posted too, since I'm new to this stuff any extra information is more than welcome. Thanks a lot!